# MarginY-32 value in Tailwind body content. How use devtools to find the value in code

Tags: css, sass, tailwind-css

Hope somebody can help me.

I want to know the code to adjust the y-axis margin of div

Comment: Please specify what you want to do. With this alone we can't help you
[help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Explain bit more what you exactly want

Answer (score 0):

I think the y-axis is probably high, so I answer on that premise.

If you adjust the margin and padding with css and sass or scss, the height will change

```css
.main {
  background: #ffffff;
  border: #00ff00 1px solid;
}

.space {
  height: 20px;
}

.h1 {
  color: #ff0000;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: #000000 1px solid;
}

.p {
  color: #ff0000;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  border: #000000 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="h1">
    <h1>Main</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="space"></div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="p">
    <h1>Main</h1>
  </div>

</div>
```

With this feeling, you can adjust the height and adjust the height around or inside

If you write in scss

```
main {
  background: #ffffff;
  border: #00ff00 1px solid;
}

space {
  height: 20px;
}

h1 {
  color: #ff0000;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: #000000 1px solid;
}

p {
  color: #ff0000;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  border: #000000 1px solid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For using y-axis margin in **tailwind**, you can use `my-{size}` for example `my-1` is:

```
{
  margin-top: 0.25rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.25rem;
}
```

for know about another sizing you can follow [tailwind doc](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/margin).